# How to make single war file of 4 modules in maven?

Tags: maven

I am new in Maven. Currently i am working on maven and make a single war file of diff module. My Project divided into to 4 module they are :

1. Common :: This is common among all module and contains all businesses and DAO layer.
2. Service Layer : This is service layer and all client interact with it.
3. Customer Portal : This is dashboard of custome.
4. Admin Portal : This is dashboard of admin.

I want make a single war file inside all above mentioned module.

Please any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the dependency order

```
common -> service -> customer -> Admin
```

Meaning

`Service` module `pom.xml` contains dependency as

```
<dependeny>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
</dependeny>
```

similarly for all the above modules.

`Admin` can be the maven module which build `war` to you.

For this, we use [WAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) assembly plugin.

make `<packaging>war</packaging>` for the `Admin` module.

If dependencies are in any other order, specify on the highest module and all the other dependencies are added as `jar` files under `WEB-INF` folder.

---

[EDIT]

common -> pom.xml

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

service -> pom.xml

```
<dependencies> 
<dependeny>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
</dependeny>
</dependencies>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

customer -> pom.xml

```
<dependencies> 
<dependeny>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
</dependeny>
</dependencies>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

admin -> pom.xml

```
<dependencies> 
<dependeny>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>customer</artifactId>
</dependeny>
</dependencies>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

This way, you can create only one war file and rest becomes jar.

Comment: Thanks for the guiding me. Currently i am doing same way and after build parent project make three war. The Dependency are common -> service;; common -> customer;; common -> Admin alls(service, customer, admin) has as you mentioned above. I dont want 3 war. i want only one war which contains alls.

Comment: @TarunKumar Please check the EDIT section. every other packaging should be jar file.